# What's the recommended way to use a specific tensorboard's web component?

Tags: polymer, tensorboard, bazel

I would like to use some of tensorboard's web-components independently, for example `tf-scalar-card.html`. However
the bazel build vulcanizes all the components into a single html file. What's the right way to build & consume a single web component to embed it in an external project?

Comment: Hi, I know Bazel but I don't know Tensorboard. Could you update your question with repro instructions (e.g. what git repo to clone, which commit to check out, what Bazel command you ran with with Bazel version and on which OS) and pointing out what happens vs. what you want to happen?

Comment: And also could you show what build rules or build commands you tried so far and where you got stuck?